# How to use/import http module?

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I've been playing with [Angular 2 Quickstart](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html).

How can I use/import http module in Angular 2?

I've looked at [Angular 2 Todo's.js](https://github.com/davideast/ng2do/blob/master/todo.js), but it doesn't use the http module.

I've added `"ngHttp": "angular/http",` to `dependencies` in `package.json` because I've heard Angular 2 is somewhat modular.

Comment: Here is wrapper for making XHR calls from Angular 2 : https://github.com/arvindr21/ng2do-mean-app/blob/master/public/services/xhr-factory.es6 You can go through the above code repo to see how it is consumed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In version 37 you need to do this:

```
///<reference path="typings/angular2/http.d.ts"/>    
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
```

And run this tsd command:

```
tsd install angular2/http
```

Comment: the ///reference is no longer needed, tsc since 1.6.2 , expects to find angular/http.js inside node_modules and next to it should be a  angular/http.d.ts  this is suppose to become sort of standard, IDE were this works now are latest VS code , the Early Access of WebStorm, and there is a microsoft plugin for sublime text
you can see this working in the latest tutorial in the angular.io

Comment: Github of the angular heroes tutorial where it can be seen working
https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/

Comment: I don't see [any references](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=http) to `angular2/http` in the demo anymore @GabrielGuerrero

Answer (score 51):

**Last update: May 11, 2016**

**Angular version: 2.0.0-rc.2**

**Typescript version: 1.8.10**

[Live working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2BBBwS).

A simple example of how to use the Http module with Observable:

```js
import {bootstrap} from '@angular2/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {Component, enableProdMode, Injectable, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS, URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

const API_KEY = '6c759d320ea37acf99ec363f678f73c0:14:74192489';

@Injectable()
class ArticleApi {
  constructor(private http: Http) {}
  
  seachArticle(query) {
    const endpoint = 'http://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json';
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams()
    searchParams.set('api-key', API_KEY);
    searchParams.set('q', query);
    
    return this.http
      .get(endpoint, {search: searchParams})
      .map(res => res.json().response.docs);
  }
  
  postExample(someData) {
    const endpoint = 'https://your-endpoint';
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    
    return this.http
      .post(endpoint, JSON.stringify(someData), { headers: headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `<ul>
                <li *ngFor="let article of articles | async"> {{article.headline.main}} </li>
             </ul>`, 
  providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, ArticleApi],
})
class App implements OnInit {
  constructor(private articleApi: ArticleApi) { }
  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.articles = this.articleApi.seachArticle('obama');
  }
}

enableProdMode();
bootstrap(App)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Incidentally you can just use http.get instead of http.request. :)

Comment: On alpha.35 -- When I tried to use Observable, I got below exception, not sure if I need to create and instance before. "ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: rx_1.Observable.fromEvent is not a function"

Comment: replace "angular2/angular2" with "angular2/core" in recent versions

Comment: @harryB Thank you, I updated to beta.1 and include your suggestion

Comment: Updated to angular-2.0.0-rc.2

Answer (score 25):

1. We are working on a separate data persistence layer, that will cover HTTP. This is not finished yet.
2. Because of `Zone` in Angular 2 you can use any existing mechanism for fetching data. This includes `XMLHttpRequest`, `fetch()` and any other third party libraries.
3. `XHR` in the `compiler` is meant to be private, and we can change the API at any time and as such should not be used.

Comment: I've expressed it before in other (and probably more appropriate) forums before - but I want to point out that I'm not sure why the choice was made to use Rx observables in the Http module. Especially since their API is different from ECMAScript's following type considerably, it's different from its next version (RxJS is currently being rewritten to a different API) and like you've said you _can_ use `fetch` anyway. This is betting on an already deprecated and nonstandard API for something it doesn't fit well in (according to its inventor) - but oh well, I guess you've had your reasons.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Old post, but they are planning on using [RxJS-Next](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3110).

Comment: @Misko What is the best way to find the percentage of completion when using Angular2 Http service?

Answer (score 8):

Much the same in Alpha 42, but it can be noted that `Headers` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` also come from `angular2/http`.

```js
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

export class App {

  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  getThing() {
    this.http.get('http://example.com')
      .map(res => res.text())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.thing = data,
        err => this.logError(err),
        () => console.log('Complete')
      );
  }

}
```

More on this and how to use observables that get returned over here: 
https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/15/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/

:)

Answer (score 6):

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Injectable()
export class GroupSelfService {
    items:Array<any>;

    constructor(http:Http){
        http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/src/data/names.json')
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.items = res;
            console.log('results found');
        })
    }
}
```

Results in a 404:
    File change detected
    File change detected
    GET /src/angular2/http 404 0.124 ms - 30

Two strange things:
1. /src/angular2/http - is not the path where http can be found and not the path I've provided in the code.
2. core.js lies just beside http.js in the node_modules/angular2 folder and is found.

How strange is that?

**Update**
Mea culpa: None of the examples mentioned that you need to reference the http.js in your html like
    `<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>`
...and then it worked.
But for the path in the error message I still have no explanation.

Comment: This is exactly what's happening to me - I think the weird GET is due to require just firing a request at ./anguar/http. Anyway your suggestion of including http.dev.js worked a treat

Answer (score 6):

Apart from all answers given below if i cover up with some additional points Here is `Http` how to use/import everything...

### ANGULAR2 HTTP (UPDATED to Beta !!)

Firstly as clear from name we have to import http file in the index.html like this

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

> > or you can update this via CDN [from here](https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.36/http.dev.js)

then next step we have to import `Http` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` from the bundles provided by angular.

> but yes it is a good practice to provide HTTP_PROVIDERS in the bootstrap file because by using this way it provided on the global level and available for the whole project like following.

```
bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, some_more_dependency's
]);
```

and imports are from....

```
import {http} from 'angular2/http';
```

> > ### Consuming Rest API's or json using Http

Now along with the http we have some more options provided with the angular2/http i.e like Headers, Request, Requestoptions etc etc.
which is mostly used while consuming Rest API's or temporary Json data. firstly we have to import all this like following:

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
```

sometimes we need to provide Headers while consuming API's for sending access_token and many more things that is done using this way:

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
```

now come to RequestMethods: bascially we use GET, POST but we have some more option you can [refer here...](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/RequestMethod-enum.html)

we can use use requestmethods by using `RequestMethod.method_name`

there are some more option for the API's for now i posted one example for POST request the help by using some important methods:

```
PostRequest(url,data) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))

        this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: url,
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res) {
                    return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
                }
            });
    }
```

for more info i had found two best reference [here..](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/Request-class.html) and [here...](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/10/15/angular-2-series-part-3-using-http/)

Answer (score 4):

I believe that now (alpha.35 and 36) is needed to be:

```
import {Http} from 'http/http';
```

Remember to add (since now is a separate file) the reference in your html: https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.36/http.dev.js

Comment: I'm getting a cannot find module 'http/http' error in the typescript compiler when importing it, alpha 36

Comment: @MonkeyBonkey you have to add the reference in your html: https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.36/http.dev.js

Comment: How would one do this using ES5 syntax?

Comment: Now it is angular2/http instead of http/http

Answer (score 2):

Following up on a few of the answers, here is a complete working example of using the `http` module

`index.html`

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
      });
      System.import('app/app');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <app>loading...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

`app/app.ts`

```
import {bootstrap, Component} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  viewProviders: [HTTP_PROVIDERS],
  template: `<button (click)="ajaxMe()">Make ajax</button>`
})

class AppComponent {
  constructor(public http: Http) { }

  ajaxMe() {
    this.http.get('https://some-domain.com/api/json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(
        data => this.testOutput = data,
        err => console.log('foo'),
        () => console.log('Got response from API', this.testOutput)
      );
  }

}

bootstrap(AppComponent, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its already in angular2, so you dont need to put anything in package.json

You just have to import and inject it like this. (this is a Stuff service with a methodThatUsesHttp() that just logs the response)

```
import {XHR} from 'angular2/src/core/compiler/xhr/xhr';

export class Stuff {
    $http;
    constructor($http: XHR) {
        this.$http = $http;
    }

    methodThatUsesHttp() {
        var url = 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cfgqzSXcVu?indent=2';

        this.$http.get(url).then(function(res) {
            console.log(res);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: however it doesn't work exactly like $http in angular 1.x... you have to manually parse the response according to type...

`this.$http.get(url).then((res) => {
    console.log(JSON.parse(res));
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
});`

Answer (score 1):

```
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
```

Answer (score 1):

For Angular **4.3+, 5.+**

```
// app.module.ts:

import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Import HttpClientModule from @angular/common/http
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    // Include it under 'imports' in your application module
    // after BrowserModule.
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
})
export class MyAppModule {}
```

And inside your service class

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
```

Other packages you might also need

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

In `package.json`

```
"@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
```

Reference is [here](https://angular.io/guide/http)

Answer (score 1):

just run:

```
npm install --save  @angular/http
```

and then import via

```
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
```

Comment: `import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'`: true.  `npm install --save  @angular/http`: not necessary.  "@angular/http" should already be available when the Angular project is created.

Answer (score -1):

A simple example using the http module:

```
import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, NgFor} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Http, HTTP_BINDINGS} from 'angular2/http'

@Component({
   selector: 'app'
})

@View({
    templateUrl: 'devices.html',
    directives: [NgFor]
})

export class App {
    devices: any;
    constructor(http: Http) {
        this.devices = []; 
        http.get('./devices.json').toRx().subscribe(res => this.devices = res.json());
    }
}

bootstrap(App,[HTTP_BINDINGS]);
```

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers to your own site. Instead, put the essential information in your answer itself. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212/200235)