# AngularJS - POST request reload

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am searching solution for this question more than 3 day and can't find anything..

I have ionic3 App and working width Http POST requests. I am sending requests to my php server and geting data..

My data-api.ts (provider)

```
  public getNotifications(token){
    return this.http.post(this.sharedVars.getApi(),"action=messages/notification&token="+token, this.options
    ).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

profilePage.ts

```
notifications() {
    this.api.getNotifications(this.user.token).subscribe(
      data => {
        if(data.err == 0){
          this.notifications = data.data;
        }
      },
      err => {
          console.log(err);
      }
  ); 
}
```

This is working functions and I am getting right output (1) when click this function. but on x action on my server notification count will changed to 2, 3, 4 etc.. and I want load this function not on click, but on page load. so If `this.notifications` have new value I want change value live (like as firebase)

Example 2:

I have send message action in my data-api.ts (provider)

```
  public sendMessage(token, to, message, attachment){
    return this.http.post(this.sharedVars.getApi(),"action=messages/send&token="+token+"&to="+to+"&message="+message+"&attachment="+attachment, this.options
    ).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

and also have function to get this messages.

```
  public getActivity(token){
    return this.http.post(this.sharedVars.getApi(),"action=messages/getActivity&token="+token, this.options
    ).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

so if I am making post request to `sendMessage` then I want listen live `getActivity` action and load new message in my page but not reload.. like as firebase..

I hope this question is clear. because I am not english speaker and tryng to find solution. Tanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listening actively to live events is not possible with a single HTTP request in angular.

However you might look into [eventSources](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource).
Look at this question for using with angular 2+ :
[Creating an RxJS Observable from a (server sent) EventSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827270/creating-an-rxjs-observable-from-a-server-sent-eventsource)