# Capture Streaming data in angular 2+

Tags: angular, server-sent-events, event-stream

I wanted to capture streaming data in angular. I know it can be done via Event Source API but for that the mime type has to be text/event-stream. If my mime type is for server API is application/json, then what is the way in angular to fetch stream data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36827270/creating-an-rxjs-observable-from-a-server-sent-eventsource

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.