# Using SailsJS sails.io with Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

Is there a way to instantiate `sails.io` inside the zone of a service provider in Angular2 so that websocket events trigger change detection?

A sub-question: how to RXJS to subscribe to sails.io data streams. 
I'm using Angular2 RC4, and the latest version of SailsJS.

Related question: [Angular2 View Not Changing After Data Is Updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706948/angular2-view-not-changing-after-data-is-updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It annoyed me that I couldn't give a full example of how to use Sails with Angular 2 with just plunker, so I created a [github repo](https://github.com/l2thet/Angular2-Sails-Chat), that provides the full picture on how this can work.

---

I can see how the related question you linked, would lead you down the zone path. However, you can plug all of this together without having to manually tinker with zones. [Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/rLndFvEryzaU61OHYuXT) is an example of how you could implement sails.io with Angular2 in a plunker. This leverages using RxJS to create a type of [observable](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services). You also have to implement a different version of Angular2 [change detection](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)(all of this is implemented in the plunker).

I go into a little more detail in my answer to your [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706948/angular2-view-not-changing-after-data-is-updated/38442363#38442363).

As for your sub question I'm not sure if there is a way to integrate the stream, I believe one of the intentions of RxJS was to reduce the use of callbacks, which sails.io appears to still do.

Excerpt of implementing sails.io in a service from the plunker.

```
constructor() {
  this._ioMessage$ = <Subject<{}>>new Subject();
  //self is the window object in the browser, the 'io' object is actually on global scope
  self.io.sails.connect('https://localhost:1337');//This fails as no sails server is listening and plunker requires https
  this.listenForIOSubmission();
}

get ioMessage$(){
  return this._ioMessage$.asObservable();
}

private listenForIOSubmission():void{
  if(self.io.socket){//since the connect method failed in the constructor the socket object doesn't exist
    //if there is a need to call emit or any other steps to prep Sails on node.js, do it here.
    self.io.socket.on('success', (data) => {//guessing 'success' would be the eventIdentity
      //note - you data object coming back from node.js, won't look like what I am using in this example, you should adjust your code to reflect that.
      this._ioMessage$.next(data);//now IO is setup to submit data to the subscribbables of the observer
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the syntax `<Subject<{}>>` is depreciated. The new syntax would be `this._ioMessage$ = new Subject() as Subject<{}>;`