# External promises don't trigger Angular2 change detection (UPDATE: they do)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron, bluebird

I'm working on an [electron](http://electron.atom.io) application, whose client side is written in [Angular2](https://angular.io).

I'm having the classic problem that a lot of people have encountered (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34592857/view-is-not-updated-on-change-in-angular2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31706948/angular2-view-not-changing-after-data-is-updated?rq=1)), namely that I'm updating my component's data, but the view doesn't get updated because Angular doesn't know that the data has changed. The solutions people suggest (see above and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-angular2-change-detection-manually)) is to manually run change detection, either on the whole component tree, or part of it (similar to Angular 1's `$rootScope.$digest` and `$scope.$digest`).

However, I'd like to avoid wrapping all my data changes in `zone.run()` calls, as it slightly defeats the purpose of using Angular.

I'm pretty sure I know why this happens: I'm creating Bluebird Promises outside of Angular, in electron code (ie, the [main process](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/tutorial/quick-start.md)), and these aren't Zone aware, so they don't notify Angular of the changes.

I don't know how to solve it, though. What can I do to create Zone aware promises in my electron code, to avoid having to manually run change detection all the time? Can I convert my Bluebird Promises to Zone aware Promises somehow?

<del>**EDIT**: I think I was wrong, Bluebird promises aren't Zone aware even if created within angular. They're just not Zone aware in general.</del>

**EDIT 2**: I was completely wrong in the previous edit. Bluebird promises work just fine with zones. However, in the context of an electron application, creating a promise in the *main* electron process and using it in the *renderer* process (where Angular lives), doesn't work, as the returned promise isn't zone-aware. Creating the promise from Angular code worked.

Comment: Isn't the main process the process that runs outside of the browser? I don't think any promises there would trigger changes in the browser.

Comment: I was expecting them to, because even though I'm creating the Promises in the main process, I'm requesting them and adding `.then()` handlers on the Angular side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in EDIT #2, the problem was that creating a promise in the main electron process made the promise non-zone-aware. Creating the promise from Angular solved it.

Answer (score 4):

Promises don't make Angular run change detection with `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` except when you use the async pipe  `... | async`.

When code is initialized outside Angular2 it runs outside Angulars zone. What you can do is to move initialization inside your Angular2 code or use `zone.run(...)` to move execution inside Angulars zone. There is nothing bad about `zone.run(...)`.

If the code executed only changes local properties of a component you can use `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` to run change detection for this component.

If the code causes changes in other components (like for example `this.router.navigate(...)`, then `detectChanges()` is not sufficient. For this case `zone.run()` should be used.

`setTimeout(...)` triggers change detection for the whole application and should be avoided as a way to invoke change detection manually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `zone.run()` (and `detectChanges()`) isn't *that* bad, but we have to remember to call it in the right places. In any case, that's what we're going with right now. My question is more about whether there's a way to make bluebird promises automatically behave like angular promises (which work), as bluebird promises have a bunch of useful features that native ones don't.

Comment: I don't know bluebird promises. Normal promises don't do anything special in Angular2 AFAIK, it's just that `.then(...)` is usually called because of an async call being completed in the browser, which is what Angulars zone gets notified about and then runs change detection. I would expect `bluebird` promises to work the same. Maybe a bug report in the bluebird source repository might be a good idea if it doesn't work.

Comment: I inspected a regular promise that I had created, in the dev console in Chrome, and it seemed to actually be a `ZoneAwarePromise`, which is a special wrapper around promises, provided by zone.js. That's why I think they're special.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that. I'd assume the same then.