# Angular 2 reload the current component based on user input

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, angular

In my Angular2 app, on UI input a component is loaded which pulls data from a web service. 
I want to reload the aptSearchComponent when the user input changes. Although the new data is fetched from the service base on the input, the component is not reloaded.

The input is in the headerComponent, when the user inputs some search criteria and hits enter, data is passed to the sharedService and routed to aptSearchComponent, where data is pulled from the shared service and results are displayed.

The headerComponent template stays at the top and the  aptSearchcomponent template is displayed below it.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-header',    
    template: `

            <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
              <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="search" (keyup.enter)="Search($event)">            
            </div>                   
    `,     
})

export class HeaderComponent {

  public apartments: Object[];

     constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService,private router: Router,private sharedService: SharedService) { 
       this.apartmentService=apartmentService;
       this.sharedService=sharedService;
     }


     Search(event){          
      this.apartmentService.searchApt2(event.target.value).subscribe(res => {this.sharedService.temp = res         
        this.router.navigate(['AptSearch'])});      
     }
}
```

How can I reload the component in Angular 2. Basically the data in this.aptDetails is changed, but template is still shows the old data.

```
export class AptSearchComponent implements OnInit {

    aptDetails: any;

    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService, private sharedService: SharedService,private zone:NgZone) {
    this.apartmentService = apartmentService;
    }

    ngOnInit(){      
      this.aptDetails = this.sharedService.temp;
      JSON.stringify(console.log(this.aptDetails)); //the data here is changed based on input, but the template is not refreshed and I still see the previous result. 
    }
}
```

I tried the following in constructor() but no luck

```
 this.zone.run(()=>this.aptDetails=this.sharedService.temp);
```

I am using RC4, and polyfills in not imported.

Comment: Do you really want to reload the component? or you just want to reload the  `aptDetails`

Comment: Aptdetails, it gets reloaded in the console in the current code. view doesn't change.

Comment: Where's the input? please add more information

Comment: Why reload the component? if you want reload  data when input changes try to use ngOnChanges.if you want to reload the child view use *ngIf and ng onChanges.Could you add more information?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by using @Input and ngOnChanges() hook in the child component. will share the detailed answer if anybody needs it.

Answer (score 0):

To reload it you can remove it with a simple trick.

Put an *ngIf on the component and set it to true initially.

When you want to remove it set it to false, and then using setTimeout flick it back to true instantly. This will remove it and then recreate it.

When you recreate it pass the new parameters you want to pass in from the parent component.

(Angular2 used to use this trick to reset a form, I'm not sure if a better way is available now but during RC this was the correct approach).

Answer (score -1):

Change detection only work if the property reference changed.

You must reset aptDetails before updating it.

```
this.aptDetails = {} // or whatever type it is
this.aptDetails = this.sharedService.temp;
```

Comment: Can you add more information to your original question ? like how to you manage the userinput? are you using a FormControl ?

Comment: added more details