# Using http rest apis with angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, http

So, I am following angular 2 guides on their website via typescript and am stuck at http api integration. I'm trying to make a simple application that can search via soundcloud api for a song, however I have difficulties implementing and understanding how to get going and online resources do it in so many different ways (I believe do to rapid angular 2 syntax changes back in the day).

So at the moment my project looks like this

```
app
  components
    home
      home.component.ts
      ...
    search
      search.component.ts
      ...
    app.ts
    ...
  services
    soundcloud.ts
  bootstrap.ts
index.html
```

Nothing fancy going on in the example, main files would be

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/router';

import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {SearchComponent} from './search/search.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/app.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/home', name: 'Home', component: HomeComponent, useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/search', name: 'Search', component: SearchComponent}
])

export class App { }
```

**bootstrap.ts**

```
    import {App}     from './components/app';
import {bootstrap}        from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';

bootstrap(App, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS
]);
```

And I was trying to figure out **soundcloud.ts** however am not able to and there are errors in following approach i.e. `@Inject` is not found (I assume I am using outdated syntax here). Essentially I would like to use soundcloud service for api calls within my app form search component.

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {Http} from 'angular2/http'

@Injectable()
export class SoundcloudService {
 http : Http

 constructor(@Inject(Http) http) {
   this.http = http;
 }
}
```

soundcloud api not included here as I can't get basics down first.

Comment: add the HTTP_PROVIDERS in your boot file and make sure you added the http.dev.js library and change the `@Inject(Http) http` for `http:Http`

Comment: The error you are getting is because you are importing `@Injectable` but not `@Inject` and you are using both

Comment: @Langley Could you expand n your coment please? http.dev.js needs to be aded as script in index.html? and I am not sure how I need to change the second part.

Comment: Added them as an answer, more readable that way.

Comment: Here is an article about Http if you are interested http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Well good answer provided by @langley but I would like to add some more points so posting as an answer.

First of all for consuming Rest APIs we need the `Http` and `HTTP_PROVIDERS` modules to be imported. As we are talking about Http the very first step is obviously.

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

> But yes it is a good practice to provide `HTTP_PROVIDERS` in the bootstrap file because by using this way it is provided on a global level and is available to the whole project like this.

```
bootstrap(App, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS, some_more_dependencies
]);
```

and the imports to be included are....

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
```

Sometimes we need to provide `Headers` while consuming API's for sending `access_token` and many more things which is done this way:

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))
```

Now to **RequestMethods**: bascially we use GET, POST but there are some more options you can [refer here...](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/http/index/RequestMethod-enum.html)

We can use requestmethods as `RequestMethod.method_name`

There are some more options for the APIs but for now I have posted one example for POST request which will help you by using some important methods:

```
PostRequest(url,data) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))

        this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: url,
            headers: this.headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res) {
                    return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
                }
            });
    }
```

you can [refer here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Request-class.html) too for more info.

see also -

- [How to deal with http status codes other than 200 in Angular 2.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052710/5043867)

## Update

import has been changed from

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http';
```

to

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: 'data' is not defined.

Comment: @SebastianOlsen `data` is parameter passing from component to service.

Comment: I'm an idiot, I didn't realize it was a POST request. It works flawlessly, thanks!

Comment: hehe...its okay :p

Comment: Warning, since Angular 5 the `Http` service from `@angular/http` is deprecated. You should use the `HttpClient` from `@angular/common/http` insteed.

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this line:

`<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>`

in your index.html file.

You need to add `HTTP_PROVIDERS`:

```
bootstrap(App, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

in your boot.ts/bootstrap.ts file, and import them of course.

You need to import `@Inject` in your `DojoService` class file:

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from 'angular2/core'
```

Just like you imported `@Injectable`.