# How to get post parameters in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I am not able to get the post parameters in my node js ,when I put console it says undefined but when I post parameters from postman it is working.Can anyone suggest help, please?

```
exports.login = function( req, res ) {
console.log(req.body)
  var query = 'select * from profile where email = ? and password = ?'; 
 connection.query(query,[req.body.email,req.body.password],function(error,result,rows,fields){
    if(!!error){console.log(error)
      console.log('fail');
    }else{
      console.log(result);
      res.send(result);
    }
  // }

  });}
```

My Express code,

```
    var express = require('express')
  , cors = require('cors')
  , app = express(); 

var admin = require('../controller/user'); 
 router.post('/login',cors(), admin.login);
```

Answer (score 2):

Always put `body-parser` before all route. Like this

```
  var app=express();
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Other wise always get `undefined body` value if you use it before any route since body not parsed yet.

Comment: Thank you it worked but getting the data to server like this

Comment: { '{"email":"s@gmail.com","password":"1"}': '' }

Comment: How are you passing data from client side?

Comment: headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        this.http.post(this.header1+'login', JSON.stringify(form), { headers: headers })

Comment: your JSON is not coming properly

Comment: what might be the problem

Comment: application/json.

Comment: yes, that's why you were getting the proper value.
Here are any specific reason to pass as application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: You should remove content type and if you are parsing JSON to string you should also remove that

Comment: i am finding any data being sent to server when i removed that

Comment: headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
        this.http.post(this.header1+'login', form, { headers: headers })

Comment: Can you try with this type of header setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
It should work

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088479/how-to-submit-a-form-using-angular-2-http-post-function-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to use `bodyParser`. First install it using command

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

Then add the following to your app

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // support json encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies
```

After that you can use `req.body`

Comment: As I understand the first code is separate file, let's call it `Admin module`, and `admin.login` in the second code example refers to that file. So you have to use `body-parser` in `Admin module` file