# Angular2 - How to chain async service calls (http requests) in a component?

Tags: http, asynchronous, angular, chaining

I have a component which first need to call a service that POST something. Then in the same component I want to wait until the POST is done, to call another service which GETs data.

How can I make the GET call wait for the POST call to finish?

In new-version.component.ts:

```ts
private createNewVersion(value) {
    ...

    // create new version, then call on all available versions

    // POST call
    this._newVersionService.createNewVersion(vnr);

    // GET call
    this._versionService.getAvailableVersions(); 

    ...
}
```

In new-version.service.ts:

```ts
export class NewVersionService {

response$: Subject<any>;

constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.response$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
 }

public createNewVersion(versionNr) {    
    this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/' + versionNr, null, {
        method: 'POST',
    })
    .subscribe(response => {
        this.response$.next(response.status);
    },
    error => console.error(error));
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have an example of a chained call in here:http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-2.0-and-http My sample is a get, but you can change it to a post

Answer (score 7):

When a call returns a `Promise` chain the calls with

```ts
someFunction() {
  return returnsPromise()
    .then(result => doSomethingNext())
    .then(result => doSomethingAfterThat());
}
```

Ensure you have a `return` that returns the `Promise` of that chain so the caller of `someFunc()` also has a chance to time additional work to execute after `doSomethingAfterThat()` is completed.

When a call returns an `Observable` then use the `complete` callback

```ts
someFunction() {
  return returnsObservable()
    .subscribe(
      event => doForEachEvent(),
      error => handleError(),
      () => doSomethingNext()
          .then(result => doSomethingAfterThat());
}
```

`doSomethingNext()` is executed after the last `event` and `doSomethingAfterThat()` is again chained with `then()` to show how to mix observable and promise. `doSomething()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to `concat` to achieve sequence, and `reduce` to collect the emitted values:

```
var a = this._newVersionService.createNewVersion(vnr);
var b = this._versionService.getAvailableVersions(); 

Rx.Observable.concat(a, b).reduce((acc:Array<any>, x:any) => {
    acc.push(x); return acc;
}, []).subscribe(t=> { 
      var firstEmitted = t[0];
      var secondEmitted = t[1];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
Change createNewVersion to:

```
public createNewVersion(versionNr) {
 return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/nod_inspection_plugin/services/' + versionNr, null, {
    method: 'POST',
 });
}
```

Then in your call:

```
this._newVersionService.createNewVersion(vnr).subscribe(response=> {
 this._versionService.getAvailableVersions(); 
}, error => console.error(error));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do the same is to `subscribe` in the `new-version.component.ts` and call you `GET` request from within the `POST` request i.e check whether your `POST` request is done Correctly or not
if yes `POST` is done Properly then call you `GET` request. As below:

In new-version.component.ts:

```
 private createNewVersion(value) {
    ...
    // create new version, then call on all available versions

    // POST call
    this._newVersionService.createNewVersion(vnr)
        .subscribe((res) => {
            if(res){
                console.log(res);
                if (---Post request done properly check via status or something else here----{
                    CALL YOUR GET REQUEST HERE.....
                    // GET call 
                    this._versionService.getAvailableVersions(); 
                }
                else {
                    DO something else whatever you want....
                }
            }
        });
    ...
}
```

In new-version.service.ts:

```
export class NewVersionService {

response$: Subject<any>;

constructor(private _http: Http) {
    this.response$ = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
 }

public createNewVersion(versionNr) {    
    this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/nod_inspection_plugin/services/' + versionNr, null, {
        method: 'POST',
    })
    .map(response => {
        return [{status: response.status, json: response.json()}];
    },
    error => console.error(error));
}
```

for more info related to `http` request you can [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867).

Comment: Did you ever read your own code? Your code is unreadable. Probably thats the reason

Answer (score 0):

Better use `switchMap()` here.

```
const versions$ = this._newVersionService.createNewVersion(vnr)
                 .switchMap(response => this._versionService.getAvailableVersions());

versions$.subscribe(response2 => this.versions = response2)
```

But the problem will be if you make another POST request before first has been resolved, the previous request will get cancelled.