# Google Cloud Endpoint with Angular2

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, angular, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using app-engine on the backend, with **Google Cloud Endpoints** to expose APIs for the front end. The Front end is using Angular2.

I have followed the strategy described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/calling-from-javascript) for javascript (or [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications) for Angular1), and this pretty much works but does not blends in well with Angular2  at the moment as it is not Observable based, not wrapped in a service etc.

On DefinitelyTyped, I found [these](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/gapi.auth2/gapi.auth2.d.ts) type definitions for Google Sign-In API but is only for authentication.

If no better strategy is identified, I'll end up writing a wrapper service for Gapi, but maybe someone has a better approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using http rest apis with angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34755350/using-http-rest-apis-with-angular-2)

Comment: Brent, the question you linked is about Http. My question is about Google Cloud Endpoint specifically.

Comment: My mistake, I thought it was about Angular2.  I have retracted the close vote.  I would recommend that you add a little more detail about a specific question instead of the broad question of a better approach.

Comment: Any updates on this particular project? Was a wrapper-service ultimately what you went with?

Answer (score 0):

How about you use Promise?

maybe.service.ts

```
function getPerson:  Promise<FooBarResponse>(){
  var arg:ArgFooBarPeople = new ArgFooBarPeople();
  return new Promise<FooBarResponse>(
            (resolve,reject) =>
            { gapi.client["foobarapi"]["person"].all(arg).execute(
                    (response:any)=>{
                        resolve(response);
                    });
            }
        );
}
```

maybe.component.ts

```
function load(){
    this._foobarService.getPerson()then(
             (response:FooBarResponse):void =>{
                    console.log(response);
                    this.fooBarResponse = response;
        }).catch( (error)=>{this.error="error !!"});
}
```