# How to deal with http status codes other than 200 in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

Right now the way I do http requests (borrowed from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/4937981)) is this:

```
POST(url, data) {
        var headers = new Headers(), authtoken = localStorage.getItem('authtoken');
        headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');

        if (authtoken) {
        headers.append("Authorization", 'Token ' + authtoken)
        }
        headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');

        var requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
            method: RequestMethod.Post,
            url: this.apiURL + url,
            headers: headers,
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })

        return this.http.request(new Request(requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
                return { status: res.status, json: res.json() }
            }
        });
    }
```

This works fine, except for the fact that angular2 will fail if the status code returned is anything else than 200. For example, if a user wants to post something and the server returns 400, angular 2 will throw the exception:

> uncaught exception: [object Object]

How can I avoid this? I'd like to handle these status codes in my app in order  to enhance user experience (show errors, etc)

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#handling-request-errors

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes you can handle with the catch operator like this and show alert as you want but firstly you have to import `Rxjs` for the same like this way

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res) {
                    if (res.status === 201) {
                        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
                    }
                    else if (res.status === 200) {
                        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
                    }
                }
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status === 500) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 400) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 409) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
                else if (error.status === 406) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
            });
    }
```

also you can handel error (with err block) that is throw by catch block while `.map` function,

like this -

```
...
.subscribe(res=>{....}
           err => {//handel here});
```

## Update

as required for any status without checking particluar one you can try this: -

```
return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
            .map((res: Response) => {
                if (res) {
                    if (res.status === 201) {
                        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
                    }
                    else if (res.status === 200) {
                        return [{ status: res.status, json: res }]
                    }
                }
            }).catch((error: any) => {
                if (error.status < 400 ||  error.status ===500) {
                    return Observable.throw(new Error(error.status));
                }
            })
            .subscribe(res => {...},
                       err => {console.log(err)} );
```

Comment: Is it possible to not have to write every status code as a condition? As in just return the status, and then my components can determine what to do with those status codes.

Comment: yes you can just return the error without checking status that depends on you how you want to handel the error block.

Comment: Could you edit that in? Having a hard time trying to do that with your existing example.

Comment: i have updated my answer check it once @SebastianOlsen

Comment: This seems to log into the console, which is not what I am looking for. I just want it to return the status code, without throwing an error in the console.

Comment: than just use `err.status` simply .

Comment: Seems like using the subscribe method worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: @PardeepJain, are there no constants other than using the numerical values? e.g. springs HttpStatus.OK or HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST (org.springframework.http.HttpStatus)?

Comment: @ArtanisZeratul yes there may be, you need to customise accordingly.

Comment: sorry @PardeepJain, there is actually a library for that already. its http-status-codes, you can check it from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-status-codes

Comment: have a scenario that the call is success and 'res' is empty; then my 'res.status' is undefined. @PardeepJain

Comment: @Johnsackson Now we have option for interceptor , that would be great if you want to use in such scenarios

Comment: better to use catchError in pipe for errors

Answer (score 0):

**Include required imports and you can make ur decision in handleError method**
Error status will give the error code

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from "rxjs/index";
import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {ApiResponse} from "../model/api.response";
import { TaxType } from '../model/taxtype.model'; 

private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
  // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
  console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
} else {
  // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
  // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
  console.error(
    `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
    `body was: ${error.error}`);
}
// return an observable with a user-facing error message
return throwError(
  'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  };

  getTaxTypes() : Observable<ApiResponse> {
return this.http.get<ApiResponse>(this.baseUrl).pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
);
  }
```