# Angular2 http response body on error

Tags: angular, angular2-http

```
this.http.put(url, data)
    .map(response => response.json())
    .subscribe(
      response => console.log(response),
      error => console.log(error),
    );
```

On success it outputs the data returned from the API. On error the output is ProgressEvent with status of 0.

#### How to get the response data from the API when error occurs?

Comment: Have you tried looking at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052617/how-to-deal-with-http-status-codes-other-than-200-in-angular-2 ?

Comment: Yes, it returns the same ProgressEvent in the catch block too. Also worth of mentioning the Angular version: 2.2.1

Comment: Is it perhaps possible that the progress event is only a first of two events and the regular error event only comes after it? Or does the http call only trigger this one progress event and nothing afterwards?

Comment: Only this one response is given, nothing afterwards. The status code from the API is 422

Comment: That's odd. Can you provide a demo/fiddle/plunker? Have you tried testing the API in Postman? Does it behave the same way there?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/gV0oeVaP0uWci2Up1KxS?p=preview

Comment: This looks like a cross-origin issue (look for CORS). The request fails on the OPTIONS command and therefore the server probably does not even receive the request. The error is raised by client browser before sending the actual PUT request to server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132209/discussion-between-jari-pekkala-and-matey).

Comment: @JariPekkala actually I have this same issue and would like to know what you guys found out…

Comment: @Kunepro it was indeed related to the API. I was using Laradock/Docker nginx container that didn't like OPTIONS sometimes

Answer (score 0):

You can probably try

```
this.yourHttpCall().subscribe(
        val => {
            //do something
        },
        err => {
            let error = (() => { try { return JSON.parse(err._body) } catch (something) { return err })()
            console.log(error);
        }

    );
```

That's kind of a hack around it. Not sure if it works for your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `_body` property in response, like:

```
this.http.put(url, data)
.map(response => {
  if (response['_body']) { // check response here.
    return response.json()
  } else {
    return {} // or return null.
  }
})
.subscribe(
  response => console.log(response),
  error => console.log(error),
);
```