# 401 Unauthorized error for POST request in Ionic 2?

Tags: angularjs, ionic2, http-post, ionic3

I have a problem authenticating a user. In case of problems in the credentials (email and password), I display an error message with a toast. But since this morning, I have the error 401 Unauthorized that appears and so the toast no longer displays error messages. I do not understand where it comes from.

The console's error

```
POST UrlAPI 401 (Unauthorized)
EXCEPTION: Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: UrlAPI
```

And this is my POST request

```
return this.http.post(link, data, options)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe((response) => {
            console.log("RESPONSE: ", response);
            if (response.status === 'ok'){
              this.UserData.setSessionId(response.session_id);
              console.log("SESS_ID SAVED", this.UserData.getSessionId());
              this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);
             }
            else {
              let toast = this.toastCtrl.create( {
                  message: response.errors,
                  duration: 3000,
                  position: 'top'
              });
            toast.present();
          }
        });
```

Reponse Headers

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:57
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Tue, 23 May 2017 13:49:56 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
```

Request Headers

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:fr-FR,fr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:16
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Host: UrlAPI
Origin:http://localhost:8101
Referer:http://localhost:8101/?ionicplatform=ios&ionicstatusbarpadding=true
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Angular Http service throws an error when a status code other than `2xx` is returned from the server or if the server times out.

This is dealt with by inserting an observable catch between the .map and .subscribe, OR by adding a second parameter to the subscribe, which is an error handler.

*Solution 1*

```
.map( ... )
.catch( /* handle error here */ )
.subscribe( ... )
```

*Solution 2*

```
.map( ... )
.subscribe( 
    (response) => { ... },
    (error) => { /*handle error here */ }
)
```

See **this similar question** for an example:
[How to deal with http status codes other than 200 in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052617/how-to-deal-with-http-status-codes-other-than-200-in-angular-2)