# Angular error page component using route with id without redirection

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, angular-routing, angular-router

I need your help to implements my 404 component for child route with id, without redirection to a "404" page. This child route has a resolver that fetches my API. When the API return a 404, I want to redirect to show my 404 component but without redirection.
Here's my code:

routing.module.ts

```
 const route = [
 ...
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ChildComponent,
    resolve: {
      data: ChildResolver,
    },
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: ErrorPageComponent,
  },
...
```

child resolver

```
...
  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ChildItem> {
    return this.fetch(route.params.id);
  }
...
```

NB: `ErrorPageComponent` is a dumb component who just displays the error message.
Ps: Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Thanks a lot,
Best regards
William

Answer (score 0):

There can be two ways of doing this:

1. If you get an error from the API, you can create custom message based on that ex: 404 - 'Page Not Found'.
2. You can redirect to the global error handler with a custom message which you don't need, but can be an option to consider.

> If you get an error from the API, you can create custom message based
> on that ex: 404 - 'Page Not Found'.

```
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
...
 public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ChildItem> {
    this.fetch(route.params.id).pipe(catchError((err) => {
      return of(err);
    }));
  }
```

In the child component, based on the received error message/code enable the ErrorPageComponent in the child component using `ngIf`.

You must be checking the status codes received from the response if not you can implement that using this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37052710/7025699).

> You can redirect to the global error handler with a custom message
> which you don't need, but can be an option to consider.

```
import { Observable, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
...
 public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<ChildItem> {
    this.fetch(route.params.id).pipe(catchError((err) => {
      if (err.status === 404) this.route.navigate['/ERRORPAGECOMPONENT'] 
      return EMPTY
    }));
  }
```

You can check here for how to [handle errors](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-route-resolvers) in resolve.

Comment: Okay, thanks I'll try the two way and see if one of them work for me :)