# Set headers on get request angular 2

Tags: angular, get, header, xmlhttprequest, http-status-code-406

I try to set an Authorization header to a GET request to authenticate users to a rest API. I'm using Angular 2 RC1. (I'am a total beginner).

```
getTest(){
    let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http
      .get(this._url,options)
      .map(res => console.log(res));
  }
```

I allow CORS in my backend.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Request-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization");
```

My console :

> OPTIONS api/userProfile/
>
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load /userProfile/. Response for preflight has
>   invalid HTTP status code 406

[My request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eHnv.png)

Any idea ?

Comment: see here complete example http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think that you need the `Accept` header rather because of the 406 status code...

```
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
let headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json' });
headers.append('Authorization', `Bearer ${authToken}`);

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
return this._http
  .get(this._url,options)
  .map(res => console.log(res));
```

This allows you to tell the server which content type you expect in the response...

The `Content-Type` header is rather to specify the type of the content you sent in the request. In your case, there is no content...

Comment: I see, it seems that the second header is the problem now. Without it, it works fine but with the Authorization header, it's not working, 406 status code. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Perhaps you use the `withCredentials` property to `true` within the request options. It's available from RC2...

Answer (score 1):

```
autorization =  { Authorization: 'Token adfasdfadf651f65asd1f65asdf' }

this.http.get(url, { headers: autorization})
```