# Synchronous functions - in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular2-http

I need to reach in the Angular synchronous functions (that the other waiting for the end of the first).

For example, I have two providers (MenuProvider and ShopProvider).

MenuProvider has a method :

```
getMenuItemsForCurrentShop()
```

that over HTTP retrieves the menu items for the current shop.

ShopProvider has a method:

```
setCurrentShopById(idShop:number)
```

that sets via HTTP which the shop is currently used.

I need to "getMenuItemsForCurrentShop()" called after "setCurrentShopById(idShop:number)". Ideally without callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some difference in a way how you are going to handle this situation in angular1 vs angular2.

Typical approach for angular1 is to use promises, i e your first provider method will return promise , and all you do is call `.then` method on the return object, passing `callback` function that will accept result of first method and you will call second method inside it.

For an example of this technique you can see @Pankaj answer.

Angular2 is different in this sense as it started using ReactiveExtensions library ( [rx.js](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) ). So every component likely to return `Observable<Someth>` which provide a lot more methods to work with it compared to promises. (You still can use promises approach with observables though).

For an example of how to use angular2\http module see another question: [Angular 2: How to use/import the http module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28910864/angular-2-how-to-use-import-the-http-module)

Also take a look at [http module docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/Http-class.html) in angular2

**ShopApi.ts:**

```js
import {Injectable, bind} from 'angular2/di';
import {Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rx'; 
   
@Injectable()
export class ShopApi {
  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  setCurrentShopById(idShop:Number) {
    return this.http.get('http://myservice.com/current/shop/', idShop)
    .toRx()
    .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getMenuItemsForCurrentShop() {
    return this.http.get('http://myservice.com/current/shop/items')
    .toRx()
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Angular2 way. but AFAIK you can convert observables to promise using `.toPromise()` function over your observable, so that you could use `.then`, instead of `subscribe`, but yes, I'd love to follow promise pattern by converting `observable` to promise, as most of developers are familiar with it.

Comment: @PankajParkar yeah i subtly mentioned it. As for promises vs observables, I find observables to be nicer api when you need to compose multiple sources of events together ( i.e. first page open or key pressed or filter changed ====> load new data )

Comment: yes..I got that now..Thanks for wonderful explanation.. I'm totally new to `RxJS` & `ECMA2015`, I'll go through the API..

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't think of to make synchronous ajax to solve your problem, as they make browser hangs(bad user experience) & also stop execution of code for a while. May be in future `sync` ajax are not going to be supported by any browser.

You need to follow asynchronous way only to deal with this problem, using promise pattern would help you to solve your problem. You should call other function `setCurrentShopById` in the success function of `getMenuItemsForCurrentShop` .then function.

> I assumed `getMenuItemsForCurrentShop` function has returned promise
>   object.

```
this.getMenuItemsForCurrentShop().then((response) => {
    this.setCurrentShopById(response.artists.items);
});
```