# Get Heroes in Tour of Heroes from a REST url in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-http, angular-tour-of-heroes

After the [Angular 2 Tour of heroes tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), I found myself wondering how I would "get the heroes" if I were using a REST api.

Given that I have an API running on `http://localhost:7000/heroes` that would return the "mock-heroes" list of JSON, what is the minimum I need to do to make this "solid"?

I'm as far as understanding I should put it in `hero.service.ts`; particularly in:

```
@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
    getHeroes() {
        return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
    }
}
```

But I'm stuck on how to do this at all using a http GET, let alone do it nicely/with style.

Comment: for rest API stuff read out this best examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/34823818/5043867

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Answer (score 2):

You need to do like this,

```
@Injectable()
export class OacService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    ot: Observable<string>;

    search(term: string) {

        let serviceUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/getAutoCompleteData?search=' + term;
        this.ot = this.http
            .get(serviceUrl)
            .map(response => response.json());

        return this.ot;
    }
}
```

in this case I am returning an Observable's object which is handled from my component's class as ,

```
this.items = this._oacService.search(term);
```

and in my html template,

```
  <li *ngFor="#item of items | async" (click)="setData(item.name)">
      {{item.name}}<br/>
    </li>
```

You can refer this code from git, https://github.com/bhaskeryadav/AngularJS2.git

Comment: This worked! I just don't understand how it can work. I use your `ot: Observable<string>;` as a return for `getHeroes` function. In the app component, it expects `getHeroes` to return an array of Heroes (`Hero[]`). How can it still work?

Comment: the get method always returns observable and using subscription, I am populating its data to my local collection

Answer (score 1):

In their tutorial they use a "InMemoryDataService"

> private heroesUrl = 'app/heroes';  // URL to web api
>
> constructor(private http: Http) { }
>
> getHeroes(): Promise {
>       return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
>                  .toPromise()
>                  .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
>                     }

You can replace app/heroes with your url  and  if you get an array with objects you delete the  .data after json().data

> private heroesUrl = 'URL to web api';  // URL to web api
>
> constructor(private http: Http) { }
>
> getHeroes(): Promise {
>       return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
>                  .toPromise()
>                  .then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
>                     }

Answer (score 0):

You must leverage the `Http` class as described below:

```
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getHeroes() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:7000/heroes').map(res=> res.json());
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add `HTTP_ROUTERS` when bootstrapping your application:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ HTTP_PROVIDERS ]);
```

You need now to handle an observable instead of a promise. For more details, you can have a look at this answer:

- [How to Consume Http Component efficiently in a service in angular 2 beta?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34450131/how-to-consume-http-component-efficiently-in-a-service-in-angular-2-beta/34450948#34450948)

Comment: I think I also have to add `<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/http.dev.js"></script>`?

Comment: Then getting `angular2.dev.js:22921 EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: http is not defined in [null]`

Comment: I believe as in that post `map` should be added, and http should be `public`, and it should then be `this.http`, but now I'm stuck on how to get the json structure to be a heroes [] array.

Comment: Which data structure do you receive in the HTTP response payload? You could add it in your question... ;-)