# Angular 2 http POST

Tags: javascript, angular, rest, typescript

I start work with angular 2  and typeScript , all work great, but when i work with rest api (POST) in console log i get `Response {_body: "", status: 204, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers, type: 2… }` , despite i passed the true param for login this is my code

```
 authentification(){
        var headers = new Headers();
          headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        // headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       return this.http.post(this._postUrl,JSON.stringify({username:"abc",password:"abc"}),{headers:headers});
    }
```

and this is my web service

```
 @POST
    @Path("/admin")
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public User getDate(@HeaderParam("username")String username,@HeaderParam("password")String password) throws Exception{
        try {
            String passwordC =  AESCrypt.encrypt(password);
            User u = userService.login(username, passwordC);
            return u;
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

i think problem in my web service param in string and in angular param is json
any one can help me please and thanks.

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/34823818/5043867

http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For form-urlencoded content type you need to send data in query string format with key=value pairs. You can build this string with the help of `URLSearchParams` class from `http` module. In your case it can look something like this:

```
authentification() {

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    var params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('username', 'abc');
    params.append('password', 'abc'); // .toString() => username=abc&password=abc

    return this.http.post(this._postUrl, params.toString(), {headers});
}
```

Comment: Man love you. Just saved my a** from getting kicked :) GBY