# Making http POST request in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, rest, http-post, angular

I want to make the following POST request in Angular 2.

```
http://gearman.local.eviry.com/info
```

with body as the following

```
{"gearman_servers" :[{

    "name" : "server 1",
    "addr" : "192.168.1.115"
    },
    {
    "name" : "Server 2",
    "addr" : "192.0.1.126"
    }
    ]}
```

I have made sure that this works outside Angular 2. (Using [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en))
I have also made sure that there is CORS enabled.

Following is my angular code

```
var url = 'http://gearman.local.eviry.com' +
            '/info';
var GEARMAN_DATA = {"gearman_servers" :[{
            "name" : "server 1",
            "addr" : "192.168.1.115"
        },
            {
                "name" : "Server 2",
                "addr" : "192.0.1.126"
            }]};

        let body = JSON.stringify(GEARMAN_DATA);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        this.http.post(url, body, options)
            .map(res =>  res.json())
            .subscribe(
                data => {console.log(data);},
                err => this.logError(err),
                () => console.log('Fetching complete for Server Metrics')
            );

logError(err:Response){
        console.log("some error");
        console.log(err);
    }
```

However, doing this gives me an error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gearman.local.eviry.com/info. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Also, when I print out the error inside the `logError` function, I get the following:

http://grab.by/O7s8

It is difficult to make out what is wrong with the request.

Request Headers are as shown

```
 Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:gearman.local.eviry.com
Origin:http://evil.com/
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/gearman-ui/job-queue
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36
X-FirePHP:0.4.4
X-FirePHP-Version:0.4.4
X-Wf-Max-Combined-Size:262144
```

Response headers are as shown

```
Allow:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:4519
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Mon, 15 Feb 2016 08:32:54 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips
```

If anybody uses [POSTMAN](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en), I have the following code which works. I have to implement the same using angular.(Note that you wont be able to access `http://gearman.local.eviry.com`)

https://www.getpostman.com/collections/f14ecaf29ffd52a54534

Comment: Can you show your request and response headers? ( Dev Tools>Network>[select your request]>Headers )

Comment: Added Request Headers

Comment: for `HTTP post` take a look here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/34823818/5043867 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867

Answer (score 0):

I made a try with your request (see this plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/6sbNYgIlCMNLkyyRerEk?p=preview) and appears that the reponse of your preflighted request isn't correct:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://gearman.local.eviry.com/info. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)
```

After having a look at the reponse of this one, I have the following:

- **General**

  ```
  Request URL:http://gearman.local.eviry.com/info
  Request Method:OPTIONS
  Status Code:302 Found
  Remote Address:49.212.179.100:80
  ```
- **Response Headers**

  ```
  Connection:close
  Content-Length:293
  Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
  Date:Mon, 15 Feb 2016 08:12:44 GMT
  Location:https://gearman.local.eviry.com/info
  Server:Apache
  ```
- **Request Headers**

  ```
  Accept:*/*
  Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
  Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr-FR;q=0.6,fr;q=0.4
  Access-Control-Request-Headers:content-type
  Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
  Cache-Control:no-cache
  Connection:keep-alive
  Host:gearman.local.eviry.com
  Origin:http://run.plnkr.co
  Pragma:no-cache
  Referer:http://run.plnkr.co/IwOhToeVuXn1o1a4/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.109 Safari/537.36
  ```

The 302 status code for this request is the problem I think. Moreover I didn't see any CORS headers in its response...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually, `gearman.local.eviry.com` is available only on my local setup. And yes, CORS headers are not present, for testing purpose I have jus enabled it on Chrome on using a plugin.

Comment: Okay, I see. Is your request a cross domain one? Do you have a preflighted one (`OPTIONS`) that is executed before the target one?