# How can we use rest webservices in angularjs 2 ?

Tags: angular

I found there is  angular2/http service available in angular2 but please share best practice with me from angular2  because in past with angular there were two ways with $http and $resource  now you should understand what i mean .

If possible share snippet.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html

Answer (score 1):

Imagine a typical RESTful service with two resources:

- One regarding the list of contacts: `/contacts/`. You can get the list of contacts (GET method) or add one (POST method)
- One for a particular contact: `/contacts/contactid`. You can get the contact details (GET method), update it (PUT or PATCH method) or delete it (DELETE method).

Here is the correspond service to do that:

```
@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
  baseUrl:string = 'http://...';

  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getContacts() {
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/contacts/')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  addContacts(contact) {
    var payload = JSON.stringify(contact);

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/contacts/', { headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getContact(contactId) {
    return this.http.get(baseUrl + '/contacts/' + contactId)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  updateContacts(contact) {
    var payload = JSON.stringify(contact);

    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.put(baseUrl + '/contacts/' + contact.id, { headers })
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  deleteContact(contactId) {
    return this.http.delete(baseUrl + '/contacts/' + contactId)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Don't forget to subscribe even if no payload is received. Otherwise, the request won't be sent.

You can handle error using the `catch` operator or within the subscribed error callback according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have imported all required files for http if not then read out this answer

- [Using http rest apis with angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34758630/5043867)

First of all you have to decorate your http service class with decorator i.r `@Injectable()` , and there are lot of way of using http but as i am using which method ,i am posting here :-

To make Post request sometimes we have to send autorization key also something else by appending with headers so we have to use headers like this :-

```
this.headers = new Headers();
this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + key)
```

Than you can use request method as you required i.e Get, Post, Put, Delete.

here is simple example of Post request using http :-

PostRequest(url,data) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append("Content-Type", 'application/json');
        this.headers.append("Authorization", 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('id_token'))

```
    this.requestoptions = new RequestOptions({
        method: RequestMethod.Post,
        url: url,
        headers: this.headers,
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    return this.http.request(new Request(this.requestoptions))
        .map((res: Response) => {
            if (res) {
                return [{ status: res.status, json: res.json() }]
            }
        });
}
```

working example for Get request :-

<kbd>[Working Example of Get request](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHqS8WbdYh3TUyxeqMCS?p=info)</kbd>

see also :-

- [Angular 2: How to use/import the http module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34823818/5043867)

Answer (score 0):

Sample implementation of service looks like below -

```
@Injectable()
export class WebApiService {

    private _webApiUrl = 'http://localhost:3025/api/Employee';     
        constructor(private _http: Http) { 

        }

    getEmployees(): Observable<{}> {
        return this._http.get(this._webApiUrl)
            .map((response: Response) => <any[]> response.json())
             .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
             .catch(this.handleError)
            ;
    }

    getEmployee(id: number): Observable<IEmployees> {
        return this.getEmployees()
            .map((emp: IEmployees[]) => emp.find(p => p.ID_EMP === id));
    }

    private handleError(error: Response) {
        console.error(error);
        return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
    }

}
```

See if this helps.